# Porque as perguntas inteligentes dos iniciantes são negativadas? Será que alguém não sabe responder?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Porque as perguntas dos iniciantes são rapidamente votadas negativamente? Isso influencia na resposta que outras pessoas  poderiam dar para uma pergunta que realmente tenha um valor para quem fez a pergunta?

Comment: Eu nunca vi nenhuma pergunta inteligente ficar negativada aqui. As inteligentes podem até receber um ou outro voto negativos, mas recebe dezenas de votos positivos também. O que influencia na resposta resposta que as pessoas podem dar é justamente a qualidade da pergunta. Quando ela é ruim, ninguém consegue responder e em geral essas perguntas costumam receber negativos e serem fechadas. A pergunta tem que mostrar esforço, tem que ser bem escrita, tentar resolver um problema real, estar no lugar certo. Quem pergunta tem que ter algumas preocupações básicas para obter resposta.

Comment: Geralmente as perguntas não se adequam ao formato ou estão fora do escopo de programação (como esta, por exemplo). Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) qual tipo de pergunta é desencorajado.

Comment: Leia o [tour] e o [ask]. Se ainda não for suficiente leia a [help]. Isto vai te ajudar alcançar seus objetivos. Procure melhorar a qualidade das suas perguntas, colocar informações suficientes e obterá as respostas que deseja. Todo mundo que faz isto aqui, chega onde quer.

Comment: Obrigado por responder bigown!!  Concordo com o que você disse!! Mas quando se esta perguntando algo e de cara só vem negativismo ! O iniciante fica muito mais que desmotivado !! Os moderadores do Stackoverflow nunca ouviram falar em liberdade de expressão não? ou humildade!!

Comment: bigown Vou me esforçar nas perguntas!!

Comment: Agora a pergunta foi migrada para o meta(lugar certo), se tiver mais alguma consideração edite a pergunta,

Comment: Agora ela foi postada no lugar adequado!! Graças ao trabalho responsável de pessoas que querem fazer do mundo um lugar melhor!!  Muito obrigado!! É como dizem: "se você não encontrar a resposta no stackoverflow,você não  a encontra em lugar algum!!". Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Aqui tem umas [dicas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1249/91) de elaborar melhor as perguntas, recomendo a leitura do texto que está no link lá.

Comment: Liberdade de expressão é outra coisa e aqui tem razoavelmente. Não tem sobre tudo e nem deve ter mesmo. A única coisa que erram a mão aqui é quando fazem julgamentos morais, mas só umas 5 pessoas podem fazer alguma coisa quanto a isto e acertam na maioria das vezes (pena que não em todas), por isso julgamentos morais são perigosos. Mas quem tem o poder de fazê-los sempre acha que julga bem.

Comment: Isso é verdade!!! Me desculpe cara!!! Afinal eu acho que não fui humilde ao falar de humildade,por exemplo , da forma abordada acima!!

Comment: Acredito que isto ajude a responder [pq tem gente que fica dando voto negativo sem nem ler?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243/pq-tem-gente-que-fica-dando-voto-negativo-sem-nem-ler) - Note uma coisa, nao sao moderadores que votam negativamente, qualquer usuario com 125 pontos ou mais ja pode votar negativamente. Eu so vi duas perguntas suas serem negativadas, uma coisa vou lhe dizer falar algo como "Alguém me pode me ajudar" nao 'e nada util, todos que veem aqui estao procurando ajuda. a pergunta tem que se concentrar no problema. Outra coisa voce escreveu sem quebras de linha...

Comment: ... A leitura se torna mais dificil, nesta pergunta voce fala que baixou um projeto, mas nao fala qual http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83310/3635 ... voce pode ate achar a "pergunta inteligente", mas o problema 'e na clareza dela, ou seja provalvelmente as pessoas votaram negativamente porque faltam muitos detalhes, ninguem poderia responder pois voce nao forneceu um os detalhes requeridos neste link [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Eu nao votei negativamente, mas eu votaria pra fechar, note que fechar nao significa deletar...

Comment: ...Leia este link pra entender o que 'e uma pergunta fechada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 - Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Portugues.

Answer (score 15):

Receber votos negativos é ruim, eu sei. Quando me juntei à comunidade do Stack Overflow em Português há pouco mais de um ano eu também tive alguns percalços.

Alguns motivos, bons ou ruins, pelos quais uma pergunta é negativada podem ser:

- Difícil interpretação, portanto ninguém entende
- Mal formatada, portanto parece spam
- Pedido de "faça por mim" ou "faça minha lição de casa"
- Assunto fora do escopo do site, assim como casos limítrofes
- Atitude negativa o Autor da Pergunta (AP), como chegar criticando os outros ou o site sem razão aparente
- Pede ajuda para fazer algo que não deveria ser feito
- Pede para fazer algo ilegal ou impróprio
- O usuário tem um histórico de pergunta ou respostas ruins e acaba sendo negativado mesmo quando a pergunta não é tão ruim

A lista não é exaustiva e pode ser um choque quando a sua pergunta é negativada por algum motivo da lista acima, mesmo quando você acha que a pergunta é muito boa. Mas esse é justamente um dos motivos pelos quais eu acho muito importante participar de um site como este.

Quando você deixa sua bolha e coloca o seu trabalho para análise por pessoas com variados *backgrounds*, verá que sempre há algo a melhorar. Agora basta fazer uso de um pouco de humildade de não achar que o mundo todo está errado e certamente o site lhe ajudará a amadurecer como profissional.

Infelizmente, muitas pessoas desistem logo na primeira crítica, muitas devido ao orgulho e assim não se beneficiam.

Comment: Receber votos negativos não é ruim, pelo menos não se for algo justo. A pessoa se sentir mal porque recebeu é outro problema. O resto está perfeito.

Comment: @bigown Foi nesse sentido mesmo. Todos nos sentimos um pouco mal.

Comment: Eu quando recebo um noto negativo, claro me sinto mal, contudo tento entender o porque, assim refletindo sobre, para poder aperfeiçoar.