# Stack Overflow - Perfil de pergunta

Tags: debate

### Situação

Durante a semana participei ativamente, quase todos os dias, para analisar questões que de longa data já venho percebendo, e gostaria de por em pauta até mesmo para esclarecimento próprio.

### Caráter das perguntas

Seguindo o que diz o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) temos o primórdio do que é o stackoverflow "é um site de perguntas e respostas[...] Este site tem o objetivo de obter respostas. Não é um fórum de discussão".

#### Obtenção de pontos / auto-resposta

Contudo tenho notado que há [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80385/pra-que-serve-o-comando-git-diff) que fogem do escopo de dúvida concreta para simplesmente a obtenção de pontos - de meu ponto de vista - pois o questionante não apresenta [detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ou qualquer esforço de [pesquisa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#help-post-body) O que é totalmente diferente de uma pergunta com [auto-resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta) que é para fins de mostrar alguma peculiaridade [pesquisada.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2477/por-que-devo-usar-apenas-um-return-em-cada-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

#### Documentação

Ainda nesse quesito algumas [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80383/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-variavel-para-variavel) abordadas na qual a resposta está na própria [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), quanto a esta questão gostaria de opinião da comunidade, pois há alguns quesitos a serem analisados, como:

[1.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82756/compilador-roslyn-o-que-%C3%A9-e-porque-foi-criado/82758#comment-167847) A [documentação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338/podemos-aceitar-perguntas-que-pedem-descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-existe-em-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) esta em inglês e eu não consigo ler
2. Eu li mas não [compreendi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59839/tern%C3%A1rio-reduzido-em-php-erro-ou-mal-interpretado)

O que não destaca a questão de detalhar o motivo da pergunta, "ah, mas eu não quero dizer que eu não sei inglês", ninguém aqui nasce poliglota, e se fosse o caso se estaria perguntando no SO, e não no SOpt. Se você leu e não compreendeu, o que exatamente você não entendeu?

#### Básico / Bola de neve

Gostaria também de botar em pauta novamente [uma velha discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%C3%A3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente/2174) na qual é abordada as perguntas [básicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log) para um usuário antigo. Como o próprio @bigown destaca, ela [pode ser útil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%C3%A3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente/2174#comment-6905), mas ainda assim eu a enquadraria em obtenção de pontos, pois se trata de um usuário antigo, então ele já deve saber quais perguntas fazer. E mesmo que esteja estudando um linguagem nova, ele já é programador, sabe como pesquisar. Assim evitando a má [influencia para os novos usuários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338/podemos-aceitar-perguntas-que-pedem-descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-existe-em-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment-3408) que vão achar que [a solução para tudo é perguntar no stack](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda/1161).

#### Conteúdo para net

Em uma discussão sobre uma pergunta um dos usuários comentou que a pergunta era pertinente pois [gerava conteúdo para a internet](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/115/%C3%89-util-fazer-perguntas-que-geram-conte%C3%BAdo-para-a-net), não creio que o 
objetivo do stack seja transcrever os documentação das linguagem e gerar um repositório para pesquisa, então creio que esse tipo de argumento não é valido.
Fora que, como comentado anteriormente, poderia gerar um bola de neve de tantas perguntas básicas. Além de que, se é para fins de conteúdo para net, deveria ser uma pergunta com [auto-resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47724/como-1-pode-ser-maior-que-4).

#### Novatos

Quando uma pessoa que não conhece uma comunidade e quer fazer parte dela, é claro que ela vai cometer erros, então quando um novato faz alguma pergunta creio que ele deve ser instruído, e não [negativado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4276/porque-as-perguntas-inteligentes-dos-iniciantes-s%C3%A3o-negativadas-ser%C3%A1-que-algu%C3%A9m#comment-12278), pois como o usuário novo comenta ele se sente ruim, e perde o interesse pela comunidade, desta forma creio que a comunidade deve passar pelo seguinte processo: um voto negativo apenas, pois assim a pessoa vera que fez algo errado, e lendo os comentários vera instruções de como proceder nas novas perguntas.

### Conclusão

Ate agora eu basicamente destaquei situações na qual eu não concordo, assim devo destacar alguns pontos que os justifiquem, creio que o mais forte deles seja, "Pense em quem responde", quer dizer, fazer uma pergunta é fácil, então pense de modo contrario, "Eu consigo responder esta pergunta?". Se a pergunta for básica e está na documentação, "Faz sentido destacá-la no stack?". Se a pergunta for mais complexa, "Eu forneci detalhamento necessário para minha necessidade?".
Agora pense de modo contraria também em relação a "Ser ajudado", "eu desejo ajuda, mas estou ajudando a pessoa, fornecendo informações suficiente, para assim minimizar o tempo que ela necessite para responder minha pergunta?", e mesmo que você pense "Ah, mas a pessoa pode estar desocupada e para passar o tempo esta no stack", se você ajudá-la a minimizar seu tempo em sua pergunta, mais rápido ela pode ajuda outra pessoa.

Sei que uma comunidade tem divergências, nada é perfeito, mas gostaria que se 
manifestem a respeito, sobre o que concordam e discordam, e se possível
salientando que medida tomar.

Comment: Eu fui notificado no chat sobre isto. Todas minhas respostas anteriores já falam o que penso sobre o assunto. Todos esses pontos já foram discutidos antes. É só um usuário querendo abrir a discussão novamente porque não concorda. Queremos respostas e não apenas informação. Na maioria das vezes essas perguntas básicas geram respostas e não só informação. Elas são boas. Por outro lado tem perguntas que só gera informação, e muitas vezes nem é pergunta básica.

Comment: Sobre documentação é provável que logo seja considerado *off-topic* ;) Para o bem a SE finalmente resolveu se mexer e fazer algo para organizar melhor certas coisas: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/221800

Comment: Eu vi este tópico no chat, meu nível de inglês não é tao avançado, então irei ler quando ter mais tempo. Mas olhei por cima e vi mais ou menos do que se trata = D

Comment: Legal essa iniciativa mesmo, @bigown. Não sei se já pensaram nisso (não consegui ler todas as respostas), mas a ferramenta seria ainda mais útil em sites localizados como o nosso. Se é difícil achar boa documentação em inglês, imagine em português. Isso aí no futuro pode ser a home de cada tag, bem melhor que os atuais tag wikis.

Comment: @bfavaretto o pessoal já achou alguns problemas nessa proposta, e eu acho que eles vão errar nos detalhes, mas a ideia geral é muito boa.

Comment: Só um detalhe sobre "simples obtenção de pontos". Acho irrelevante. A pergunta é avaliada por si só, e a intenção inicial é irrelevante. Claro que é ruim que existam perguntas só para pontos, claro. Mas é imensurável, subjetivo, e, por isso, não pode afetar o julgamento da pergunta.

Comment: putz, a tal *o que é console.log* dá pano pra manga até hoje... qualquer dia vou doar todos os pontos recebidos lá pralguma resposta legal de um novato pra ver se tiro esse karma de cima...

Answer (score 11):

Antes de mais nada: **ótima pesquisa**.

Não terei condições de adentrar em detalhes para cada caso, mas posso dizer que todos os seus pontos são válidos.

Creio que devemos *educar* os usuários, antigos e novos, sobre como proceder. Isso é um trabalho contínuo e árduo que envolve repetir as mesmas coisas vez após vez.

No entanto, *não* creio que devamos ter políticas rígidas quanto a esses casos, como sair julgando e limpando conteúdo. Ainda mais porque existem muitos e muitos casos limítrofes nos quais passaríamos uma eternidade discutindo sem consenso.

Tempos atrás eu aprendi algo interessante. Há uma falácia em que uma pessoa ou um grupo pequeno de pessoas pensa saber o que todos os outros pensam ou desejam. Mesmo que juntemos os melhores e mais experientes usuários aqui do SOpt para definir regras, provavelmente eles farão um péssimo trabalho em adivinhar o que a grande massa de usuários realmente espera e busca no site. Não podemos supor ou prever que determinado tipo de pergunta vai ou não ser útil ou popular.

Um exemplo pessoal é a pergunta sobre `git diff`. Eu mesmo há um tempo atrás não sabia como lidar com o comando e a documentação que consultei na época só me confundiu mais.

O outro exemplo sobre `++` antes ou depois de uma variável também é complicado, pois o iniciante nem sempre está a par daquele super hiper manual que já tem todas as respostas. Eu mesmo demorei a *aprender a ler o manual antes de usar*. Muitos programadores simplesmente vão ao Google ou Stack Overflow antes de começar a ler qualquer documentação. Na verdade, nem podemos culpá-los completamente, pois boa documentação ainda é exceção.

Portanto, minha sugestão é:

- Deixar um bom grau de liberdade
- Educar continuamente os usuários, mas sem tentar transformá-los em robôs ou miniaturas de nós mesmos
- Vigiar, julgar caso a caso e agir quando necessário ou quando algo realmente se tornar um problema

Enfim, sei que minha resposta foi um tanto genérica, mas não vejo como responder tantos casos diversos mais diretamente.

Comment: Concordo com você quanto ao ponto de deixar livre e também de auxiliar o usuário, contudo discordo em relação a pequena maioria saber o que a grande massa pensa, pois em uma sociedade temos lideres que nos representam, nem sempre eles pensam como nos, mas se for analisado no coletivo vera que se adequá. Ha uma serie que eu assisto que mostra isso, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eANH5f1ul7s.  
Quanto a limpeza de perguntas, creio que não seria necessário, apenas auxiliar o usuário para suas próximas perguntas, assim os ensinando.

Comment: Gostei do quinto parágrafo porque o pessoal da SE acha que sabe. Por isso tem que olhar pro conteúdo e não ficar olhando pra popularidade, como só aqui no SOpt se fala nisso. Só aqui se justifica a quantidade de votos como um fator a ser considerado para deixar uma pergunta aberta. Perguntas básicas são boas, certamente atendem os novatos e muitas vezes os experientes. Perguntas que não ensinam nada verdadeiramente são ruins. Os experientes sabem quando uma pergunta não ensina nada, quando só gera um informação que gera confusão. Sempre foi assim e sempre funcionou.

Comment: @Guilherme Não estava me referindo ao sistema democrático, mas mesmo este sofre daquele mal na prática. Não fosse assim, estaríamos satisfeitos com os governantes na maioria das vezes. :)

Comment: Ótimo detalhe sobre pesquisar antes de ler documentação, eu também faço isso, se busco no Google e logo nos primeiro resultados vem uma pergunta do SO[pt|en] é claro que vou ver antes de olhar qualquer documentação, já que a probabilidade de ter um exemplo útil em uma resposta é milhões de vezes maior que na documentação, onde geralmente só explicam a parte teórica da função/método e etc. (Mas depois sempre dou uma olhada pra ver os detalhes não apontados nas respostas e perguntas.)

Answer (score 2):

O @utluiz já respondeu de uma forma excelente, mas vou ressaltar alguns pontos que fiquei preocupado com a sua argumentação.

> Contudo tenho notado que há perguntas que fogem do escopo de dúvida concreta para simplesmente a obtenção de pontos - de meu ponto de vista - pois o questionante não apresenta detalhes ou qualquer esforço de pesquisa.

Acho muito errado subestimar uma dúvida. O que pode ser simples pra você pode não ser para um outro usuário. As pessoas têm diferentes graus de entendimento e compreensão das coisas, e nem sempre buscar na internet, em outros sites, te dá uma resposta com qualidade.

Creio que a obtenção de uma resposta aqui seja com o objetivo de ter uma explicação mais sucinta e com qualidade superior ao que já existe na internet hoje, e ainda em português, o que já justifica completamente a pergunta.

Quanto a "Não demonstrar esforço de pesquisa", este ponto é um pouco subjetivo. A gente na verdade não tem como mensurar isso. O que não tem esforço de pesquisa, pra mim, é quando a pessoa vem no site e diz algo como: "Quero fazer um sistema assim e assado. Podem me ajudar?", ou ainda "Implementei um sistema dessa forma, vai funcionar?".

Pense num usuário como uma criança de 3 anos. Parece exagero, mas é este nível de paciência que é adequado para lidar com perguntas e respostas que não gostamos.

> Gostaria também de botar em pauta novamente uma velha discussão na qual é abordada as perguntas básicas para um usuário antigo. Como o próprio @bigown destaca, ela pode ser útil, mas ainda assim eu a enquadraria em obtenção de pontos, pois se trata de um usuário antigo, então ele já deve saber quais perguntas fazer. E mesmo que esteja estudando um linguagem nova, ele já é programador, sabe como pesquisar. Assim evitando a má influencia para os novos usuários que vão achar que a solução para tudo é perguntar no stack.

Aqui é mais alarmante que a primeira. Supor que "o usuário já deve saber quais perguntas fazer" é querer instrumentalizar a ação de fazer perguntas.

- O usuário **não sabe** quando uma pergunta pode ser boa ou não. Isso é uma avaliação coletiva e orgânica;
- Um usuário antigo sabe como o site funciona, e nem por isso deve ter um tratamento diferenciado por isso. O tratamento deve ser igual pra todos;
- Não considero "má influência" uma pergunta básica. Falando em "má influência", [fiz uma pergunta que é basicamente uma transcrição documentativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50247/ora-00980-synonym-translation-is-no-longer-valid) e não considero a pergunta ruim, até porque a documentação disponível em outros sites é uma porcaria, então pedi uma resposta que fosse simples e sucinta com alguma transcrição de documentação, mas também com dicas do que fazer pra procurar erros. Eu estava tendo dificuldades pra obter uma solução rápida pro meu problema, e aqui obtive uma resposta que foi realmente útil pro problema.

> Em uma discussão sobre uma pergunta um dos usuários comentou que a pergunta era pertinente pois gerava conteúdo para a internet, não creio que o objetivo do stack seja transcrever os documentação das linguagem e gerar um repositório para pesquisa, então creio que esse tipo de argumento não é valido. Fora que, como comentado anteriormente, poderia gerar um bola de neve de tantas perguntas básicas. Além de que, se é para fins de conteúdo para net, deveria ser uma pergunta com auto-resposta.

Por que não é válido? Eu vejo a auto-resposta mais como "usuário querendo obter pontos" do que "querendo gerar conteúdo para a internet", até porque as respostas têm limite de caracteres e a plataforma é inadequada para produção de artigos riquíssimos em informações e tutoriais (embora eu mesmo já tenha escrito alguns pequenos tutoriais aqui).

Aliás, em pesquisas minhas, o SOpt já aparece em primeiro lugar para muitas delas.

> Quando uma pessoa que não conhece uma comunidade e quer fazer parte dela, é claro que ela vai cometer erros, então quando um novato faz alguma pergunta creio que ele deve ser instruído, e não negativado, pois como o usuário novo comenta ele se sente ruim, e perde o interesse pela comunidade, desta forma creio que a comunidade deve passar pelo seguinte processo: um voto negativo apenas, pois assim a pessoa vera que fez algo errado, e lendo os comentários vera instruções de como proceder nas novas perguntas.

Aqui sim pensamos de maneira similar. Acho que algum mecanismo pra evitar muita negativação poderia ser implementado.

Comment: Creio que o grande problema ao meu ver é a falta de informação, como conversei hoje a tarde com @bigown, as perguntas não tem clareza ela se apresentam de um modo que não ha informação, simplesmente uma pergunta sem contexto, não dizem o que foi tentado, onde parou e o que não conseguiu realizar, ou mesmo exemplos do que se quer. Contudo de fato a muitos pontos a serem analisados e eu abordei alguns, e trouce minha opinião, mas isso é uma comunidade, não cabe a mim julgar, apenas expor ideias para que o todo decida.